# How to remove a div element when the child elements are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a list of staff organised into each department they work in. At the top of this page, I have a search box to search for names and a select box to choose the department. This works fine.
When searching for say `"Person4"` it will hide all of the other people but keep the other department headings. Is there anyway that when filtering for `"Person4"`, `"Department1"` is hidden?

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var e2 = $("#dpt").val().toLowerCase();
  var e = new RegExp(e2);
  $(departmentfilter).each(function() {
    if (e.test(this.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) 
      $(this).show();
    else 
      $(this).hide();
  });
});


$('#searchbox').bind('keyup', function() {
  var s2 = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var s = new RegExp(s2);
  $(personfilter).each(function() {
    if (s.test(this.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) 
      $(this).show();
    else 
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search Staff">
<select id="dpt">
<option  value="" selected>All Staff</option>
<option value="Department1">Department1</option>
<option value="Department2">Department2</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="departmentfilter"> Department1
  <div id="personfilter">Person1</div>
  <div id="personfilter">Person2</div>
  <div id="personfilter">Person3</div>
</div>
<div id="departmentfilter"> Department2
  <div id="personfilter">Person4</div>
  <div id="personfilter">Person5</div>
  <div id="personfilter">Person6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are `id`s not unique? Also share the markup for select and input box.

Comment: @gurvinder372 For the search function to work I had to make all the ID's the same. I'm probably doing this all the wrong way though!

Comment: @TCampbell IDs must be unique on document context so ya you are doing it wrong. Use class instead

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks but when I change the id's to class the search function stops working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use classes instead of duplicate `id`'s since the identifier should be unique in the same document :

```
<div class="departmentfilter"> Department1
  <div class="personfilter">Person1</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person2</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person3</div>
</div>
<div class="departmentfilter"> Department2
  <div class="personfilter">Person4</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person5</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person6</div>
</div>
```

Then you could hide all departements and show just the related one with the filtred result like :

```
$('.departmentfilter').hide(); //Hide all departments
$(this).closest('.departmentfilter').show(); //Show the related one
```

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var e2 = $("#dpt").val().toLowerCase();
  var e = new RegExp(e2);

  $('.departmentfilter').each(function() {
    if (e.test(this.innerHTML.toLowerCase()))
      $(this).show();
    else
      $(this).hide();
  });
});

$('#searchbox').bind('keyup', function() {
  var s2 = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var s = new RegExp(s2);

  $('.departmentfilter').hide(); //Hide all departments

  $('.personfilter').each(function() {
    if (s.test($(this).text().toLowerCase())) {
      $(this).show();
      $(this).closest('.departmentfilter').show(); //Show the related one
    } else
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="searchbox" />
<select id="dpt">
  <option  value="" selected>All Staff</option>
  <option value="Department1">Department1</option>
  <option value="Department2">Department2</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="departmentfilter"> Department1
  <div class="personfilter">Person1</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person2</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person3</div>
</div>
<div class="departmentfilter"> Department2
  <div class="personfilter">Person4</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person5</div>
  <div class="personfilter">Person6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I'm after, many thanks! Only issue is I also have a select box to select the department as well as search for a name. This isn't working anymore, any ideas?